# Maintain a session in wordpress using session-management plugin

Tags: wordpress

How do I maintain a session in WordPress. I have already installed and activated a plugin for session management. Where should I declare and assign session variables?

Thanks..!

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for this. Just put this in your theme's functions.php file:

```
/*
 * Session Tracking
 */    
    add_action('init', 'start_session', 1);
    function start_session() {
        if(!session_id()) {
            session_start();       
        }
    }
```

You can then set and access the $_SESSION super-global var anywhere in your theme files.

I use this as a way to enable "back" links for blog posts, as they have multiple parent categories, you never know the correct URL for the "back" function unless you use a session var or cookie set. See here for more details: [Advanced WordPress Single Post Pagination - Exclude Category & Browse Through Only Set Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946468/advanced-wordpress-single-post-pagination-exclude-category-browse-through-on)